# Finding out "modifyvm" values for an existing VM

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBox allows change advanced settings for the VMs using `VBoxManage modifyvm` CLI command, such as `VBoxManage modifyvm --natdnshostresolver1 on`.
However, I fail to find the way to query for the current values for of these switches, i.e. to check whether `--natdnshostresolver1` is currently `on` or `off`.
The closest I have found is to read through the `.vbox` file for this vm and try to guess which of the values corresponds to which `modifyvm` value.